# Laravel Relation Query

Tags: laravel

I have two tables `course` and `module` where each `course` belongs to a single `module`.

What I need is to eager load the `module` with `course`

**my codes is :**

```
$courses = Course::all();
$module  = Coursemdule::all();
```

Comment: Have you set up relationships between the two models?

Comment: Have you checked the docs ?, you need to define the relation between the two models first.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create relation between both the table

> In the course model

```
/**
 * Get the user that owns the phone.
 */
public function module()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Coursemdule');
}
```

> In the Coursemdule model

```
/**
 * Get the Course record associated with the Coursemdule.
 */
public function course()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Course');
}
```

To fetch this value

```
$phone = Course::find(1)->module;
```

OR

```
$phone = Course::with('module')->all();
```

I hope this will help you.